# Input file preset with a file path

Tags: html

How do you preset the filepath in a input type=file?

I want the field to already have a path in it -> Read-Only possibly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not preset the `input[type=file]` element.

The only reliable thing you can do is read back the filename with the `value` property on the DOM. Some browsers prepend a fake path, e.g. `C:\fakepath\some-file.jpg`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, it's a security issue. Doing so would let a web site operator create a form with a *hidden* file field, with a path filled in, so that when the user submits the form the browser would also upload a file of the website operator's choosing.